# BulkLoad in HBase table with Snappy Compression gets UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

When attempt to make a bulk-load from M/R into a Table with Snappy Compression enabled. I get following error:

```
ERROR mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles: Unexpected execution exception during splitting
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy()Z
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.groupOrSplitPhase(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.doBulkLoad(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:234)
```

**Table description is:**

```
DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                 ENABLED                                                             
{NAME => 'matrix_com', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 't', BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY' true                                                                
, VERSIONS => '12', TTL => '1555200000', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 't                                                                     
rue'}]}
```

If Hadoop has all snappy codecs installed, also HBase doesn't give an error when creating the table with snappy, why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems it's a bug just fixed by the Hadoop developers. please check the following link
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5799